# if в одну строку php расшифровка

Tags: php, wordpress

в вп есть такая строка:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Это тоже самое, что:

```
if ( have_posts() === true ) {
    while ( have_posts() === true) {
the_post(); ?> ...
```

или:

```
if ( isset(have_posts()) ) {
    while ( isset(have_posts()) ) {
 the_post(); ?>
```

или как-то по другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
the_post(); ?> ...
```

Вместо endif и endwhile ниже по тексту - закрывающие фигурные скобки.

Comment: а что значит аргумент в скобках? он проверяет на наличие в нем чего-то, или соответствие чему-то?

Comment: какой аргумент в скобках?

Comment: Если have_posts() возвращает не 0, то условие срабатывает, т.е. true. Если функция вернет 0, то условие не сработает и этот блок будет пропущен

Comment: Ну да, так и есть. Функция have_posts() возвращает true или false. В чем вопрос-то? Какой аргумент?

Comment: Внутри цикла while функция the_post перемещает указатель текущего поста в списке, а have_posts() все время проверяет, остались посты на вывод или нет. Так понятно?